# Format data returned from JSON in DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am reading a json file from remote url and displaying it in DataTable.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').DataTable(
            {
            ajax: {
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'https://chainformed.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Data/mostwatched.json',
                dataSrc: ''
            },
            paging: false,
            responsive: true,
            language: {
    url: "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.12.1/i18n/tr.json",
  },

            columns: [
                { "data": "id" },
                { "data": "rank" },
                { "data": "name" },
                { "data": "watchlist" },
                { "data": "percentage" },
                { "data": "difference" },
                { "data": "timestamp" }
                
            ]
        });
        $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
    });
</script>
```

I would like to be able to format and manipulate the data returned from that json file. What is the best way to do it?

For example, i would like to change the values from (**{ "data": "watchlist" }**) field to *number format with comma*. How can i achieve it?

I tried this but with no luck: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "number format" ... like "1,234,567"?

Comment: Yes, number format with comma.

Comment: In javascript Numbers have a `toLocaleString` method that you can use - of course, you'll have to modify the data you get back - is there something in DataTables that let you do that?

Comment: I know.. but i don't know how to apply it to the json response.. https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc

Comment: [Datatables numberr renderer](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers#Number-helper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `render` element.
Read document from  [Format output data - orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/outputFormat-orthogonal.html)
 and [example](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/61407/how-to-apply-a-numeric-format-to-a-column)

Another way u can use `columnDefs`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable(
        {
        ajax: {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://chainformed.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Data/mostwatched.json',
            dataSrc: ''
        },
        paging: false,
        responsive: true,
        language: {
url: "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.12.1/i18n/tr.json",
},
        columns: [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "rank" },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "watchlist" },
            { "data": "percentage" },
            { "data": "difference" },
            { "data": "timestamp" }
        ],
        'columnDefs': [
            {
              "targets": 3,
              "data": "watchlist",
              "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                  return data.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
              }
            }
        ]
    });
    $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
});
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: And they can use a [number renderer](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers#Number-helper)